# Flutter setState executing but not rerendering UI when setting parent stateless widget flag

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-android

My app has an introductory feature where it simply informs the user on an action to take, the issue is this help action text (`Container(...)`) does not get removed one the `setState()` function is called.

**Logical overview of process:**

```
-> `User launches app` 
    |-> `login` 
    |-> `show main UI (with help action if first time launch)` 
        |-> first time launch ? show help text : don't show
             | User acknowledges help text, set in preferences
```

Below are some code snippets of the dart fragments

**UiHomePage** (main UI - this is the parent UI)

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();
}

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    Widget pageDashboardUser() {
      ...
      
      // Notify UiComponentPartnerSelector if we should show help action text based on AppSharedPreferences().isFirstTap()
      Widget middleBrowseCard() {
        return new FutureBuilder(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return UiComponentPartnerSelector(
                  _displayProfiles, snapshot.data);
            },
            future: AppSharedPreferences().isFirstTap());
      }

      var search = topSearch();
      var selector = middleBrowseCard();

      return Stack(
        children: [search, selector],
      );

    return Scaffold(...)
}
```

This Widget displays a bunch of profiles with a base card, a text overlay, and a hint text component.

The main focus is `showHint` define in the constructur (true if the app is launched for the first time), `showTapTutorial()` which either returns the hint component or an empty container and finally the `_onTap(Profile)` which handles the *onclick* event of a card.

**UiComponentPartnerSelector** (sub UI - the help text is shown here

```
class UiComponentPartnerSelector extends StatefulWidget {
  bool showHint;
  final List<Profile> items;

  UiComponentPartnerSelector(this.items, this.showHint, {Key key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UiComponentPartnerSelector createState() => _UiComponentPartnerSelector();
}

class _UiComponentPartnerSelector extends State<UiComponentPartnerSelector> {
  UiComponentCard _activeCard;
  int _tappedImageIndex = 0;

  Widget showTapTutorial() {
    if (!widget.showHint) {
      return Container();
    }

    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 32),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Icon(
            Icons.touch_app,
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
          ),
          Text(
            "Touch to view partner profile",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color _standard = Colors.white;
    //
    // _cache = widget.items.map((e) => {
    //     e.imageUri.toString(),
    //     Image.network(e.imageUri.toString())
    // });

    Future _onTap(Profile e) async {
      if (!widget.showHint) {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UiViewProfile(e)));
      } else {
        AppSharedPreferences().setFirstTap(false).then((value) {
          setState(() {
            widget.showHint = false;
          });
        });
      }
    }
    
    UiComponentCard createComponentCard(Profile e) {
        ...
        return UiComponentCard(
            onTap: () {
              _onTap(e);
            },
            wImage: Center(
              child: Image.network(
                e.profileImageLink.toString(),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            wContent:
                // Center(
                //   child: UiTextLine(text: e.displayName),
                // ),
                Column(
              children: [
                topBasicInfo(),
                Expanded(child: Container()),
                showTapTutorial(),
                Expanded(child: Container()),
                bottomBio()
              ],
            ),
          );
        }

    return Container(
        child: Stack(...)
    );
```

**Problem:**

When `_onTap(Profile)` is clicked and `showHint` is `true`.

**What should happen:**

What **SHOULD** happen next is `AppSharedPreferences().setFirstTap(false)` should set the initial tap flag to `false`, then when finished `setState()` including setting `showHint` to `false`, then rerendering the UI and removing the hint text container (found in `showTapTutorial()`).

**What happens:**

What infact happens is when `_onTap()` is called, it updates the preferences correctly, `setState()` is called and `showHint == false` and `!widget.showHint` in `showTapTutorial()` is true returning `Container()` BUT the UI itself doesn't rerender.

Thus after clicking this "button" for the first time, the UI remains (doesn't change). Clicking a second time executes the `Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UiViewProfile(e)));` part **WHILE** the action help text (tutorial) is still showing. If I click on the same card again

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: please use this.widget instead of simply widget. Did that help?

Comment: You cound try awaiting the appsharedprefs process as well

Comment: why would `this` change anything?

Comment: @lrsvmb awaiting will essentially fallback to the build() method - trying to get rid of that using `FutureBuilder()`. I will also try using `this.widget`.

Comment: @lrsvmb also, where do you suggest I place the "this"?

Comment: i suggest you place it in everywhere where you mention a variable from the class (this.widget.variable) but i could be totally off track with this one